# Washing hands on Yom Kippur during pandemic

Tags: halacha

From what I understand, halacha places a limit on washing hands on Yom Kippur up to knuckles. Does anyone know of a psak which waives this limitation (up to knuckles) and allows a more extensive washing due to Covid-19?

Comment: This is a mistake. Washing any amount of body for pleasure is prohibited, even the fingers

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75403/1739

Comment: @DoubleAA but if for safety rather than for pleasure?

Comment: What are you washing your hands with?

Comment: See here from R Hershel Schachter regarding similar question on 9 Av https://www.torahweb.org/torah/docs/rsch/RavSchachter-Corona-43-July-21-2020.pdf

Comment: @Mike "safety" is not a classically recognized category. Washing dirt off your body is permitted as are ritual ablutions for purity.

Comment: @JoelK See R' Schachter's follow-up p'sak where he suggests that the level of danger from Covid is such that it is up to the individual to decide whether it meets the threshold of sakana to allow personal handwashing (if he normally washes during the year as a safety precaution, he should do so in this instance, too). He adds the proviso, however, that if your lack of handwashing might affect other people who are more concerned about this danger (e.g., if you will be touching surfaces that other people might touch), you have no right to avoid washing even if you judge the danger to be less.

Comment: @JoelK Here's the [follow-up p'sak](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/965450/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-48-washing-hands-on-tisha-b-av-part-2/), citing a number of acharonim for the principle of subjective evaluation of one's own halachic *sakana* in a case where the objective level of danger is slight/moderate.

Answer (score 4):

Washing for cleanliness *was never included in the prohibition.* The command of "afflict yourselves" was against washing for enjoyment. Sorry if there was some confusion about this.

[Rabbi Mann of Eretz Chemdah writes](https://www.torahmusings.com/2020/09/corona-policies-and-clarifications-for-yom-kippur/):

> 4. Washing with soap/cleansing with sanitizer – It is permitted to wash hands to remove dirt (Shulchan Aruch, OC 613:1). Removing germs is no less justified; only washing which can be broadly deemed as for enjoyment is forbidden. In a past column (Vayeilech 5776), we cited sources that sicha (applying oil) is forbidden even not for enjoyment (Yerushalmi, Yoma 8:1). We pointed out that sicha is when the substance is absorbed by the skin, whereas rechitza removes impurities from it, and that soap resembles rechitza. Sanitizer is on one hand, absorbed by the skin, but on the other hand, is never for enjoyment. Certainly, when it is clearly needed for hygiene, including during a pandemic even for healthy people, it is permitted (see Shulchan Aruch, OC 614:1, who permits applying oil for any truly medicinal purpose).

Comment: This may not apply if one doesn't feel dirty but is being forced to wash their hands by others who don't trust your own assessment of your hands.

Answer (score 1):

As you assert washing represents one of the 'inuyim' (afflictions) of Yom Kippur - refer to the Mishna in [Yoma 73b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.73b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

In light of the dangers posed by the pandemic many Rabbonim have paskened the necessity to wash hands and thereby negate the spread of any germs and the like even on Yom Kippur. In this useful document from Ohr Torah Stone [here](https://www.otsamiel.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-1.pdf) on p.12 (under the auspices of Rav Shlomo Riskin) in light of the virus they advise that in accordance with health guidelines, it is permissible to wash hands with cold water and liquid soap or to use wipes or alcohol.

Similarly, the [Federation Beis Din](https://www.federation.org.uk/) in the UK writes [here](https://www.federation.org.uk/faqs-tishah-bav/) in a question-and-answer format:

> ***DUE TO COVID-19, AM I ALLOWED TO WASH MY HANDS ON TISHAH B’AV AND YOM KIPPUR AS NORMAL WITH SOAP ETC.?***
>
> *During the current pandemic, washing hands is acutely necessary to prevent the spread of the disease. The halochos of Tisha B’Av and Yom kippur allow hand washing with soap and/or sanitizer as is needed to facilitate hygiene. If hands are already clean and being washed due to davening or negel vasser, then they should be washed only to the knuckles.*

Thus, one needs to be sensible in light of the virus and any make-safe actions are encouraged. You should speak your local orthodox Rov for greater clarity and guidance.

Comment: This is a poor presentation. The pandemic and health reasons would not justify pushing aside the prohibition on washing. If that was the only consideration we'd just tell everyone to stay in a room and isolate themselves all day.

Comment: I'm sorry @DoubleAA - I don't understand what the issue is. Many Rabbonim which I proved with sources say that on this Yom Kippur people are advised to wash their hands more thoroughly due to the current health risks??.

Comment: I can check your sources again but if so those rabbanim must be fired immediately

Comment: Either it's permissable to wash your hands from potential bacteria/virus every year or it's not even this year. We don't permit issurei deorayta just so people can walk outside.

Comment: That's a pretty strong thing to say(!) Especially with the Federation Beis Din in mind which is made up of some incredibly chashuv Dayonim. The quote from them does clearly discern washing for hygiene (i.e. with the pandemic in mind) vs other washing which should be done to the knuckles.

Comment: Actually the quote from them is clear that this year is no different from any other year, as I said. "The halochos of Tisha B’Av and Yom kippur allow hand washing with soap and/or sanitizer as is needed to facilitate hygiene." Nothing about pushing off prohibitions because of dangers.

Comment: Yes - and note the opening line  "During the current pandemic, washing hands is acutely necessary to prevent the spread of the disease. "

Comment: another true statement, but not a noteworthy one since it has no effect on the halacha.

Comment: "In light of the dangers posed by the pandemic many Rabbonim have paskened the necessity to wash hands" I interpreted this to mean that they made a lenient ruling due to the exigent circumstances of the pandemic, which as I noted would be mistaken (though I don't see evidence from your quoted sources that anyone did that). Did you intend it to mean that because of the importance currently of awareness of the law they were sure to publicized it?

Comment: I agree with DoubleAA that washing for hygiene was never included in the prohibition and is permitted every year. Those who allow it only this year (if they exist) probably do not believe that hygiene is a serious concern in general. Although I don't agree that we would make people isolate all day to avoid this prohibition - wearing shoes is also permitted for one who is walking a long distance.